# Django-tastypie. Nested resources, URL

Tags: django, tastypie

Can I use a nested URL

for example: /api/v1/stores/21/categories/3/products/4132/

Thanks,
Vitaliy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it's complicated and inconvinient.

[here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#nested-resources) is the recipe